# jquery parseXML: 'text/dom' is not a valid enum value of type SupportedType

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, domparser

After some changes in my project (the changes were not even related to the xml parsing part) the jquery.parseXML stopped working in firefox and chrome (I haven't tried other browsers).

I even tested very simple xml strings as

```
$.parseXML('<a>a</a>');
```

with the following result:

```
"Error: Invalid XML: <a>a</a>"
```

The internal message (catched by jquery) is the following:

```
"Failed to execute 'parseFromString' on 'DOMParser': The provided value 'text/dom' is not a valid enum value of type SupportedType."
```

This is triggered by the following jquery code lines:

```
tmp = new DOMParser();
xml = tmp.parseFromString( data, "text/dom" );
```

I really don't know how this is possible, since my changes had nothing todo with the xml parsing.

Its working if I parse it without jquery and type "application/xml", but why did the DOMParser accept the "text/dom" type before ?

**Edit**

Somehow my jquery version which I installed through bower (version 2.1.4) differs from the official version:

My version:

```
xml = tmp.parseFromString( data, "text/dom" );
```

From [jquerySource](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js):

```
xml = tmp.parseFromString( data, "text/xml" );
```

But it worked with the old version for months.

**Solution:**
So I just switched the jQuery file and its working, somehow the bower version is outdated. Nevertheless its a strange behaviour and I don't really know why it was working before, and why it stopped working from one day to another.

Comment: [**Can't reproduce**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4mw7xwg/), but generally XML should start with a doctype that sets the version and charset, you can't really expect `parseXML` to just take your HTML and assume it's XML ?

Comment: @adeneo The <a> was just an example, I'am not parsing html, even the example from jquery does not work '<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>' (event if I add a doctype) . The fiddle does work after all.